# How do I restore the default quicklists?

Tags: 12.04, unity, home-directory, quicklists

Just me with another question.

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu (I had been using Kubuntu for a while but couldn't quite get used to it), however after reinstallation I found that my home folder’s quicklists are missing. It only shows **UbuntuOne**, the rest of my home folder entries are missing. As I recall, It used to display Documents, Downloads, Music, etc..

How do I go about restoring these quicklists??

Thank you all in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a custom launcher overriding the default one.

It would be `~/.local/share/applications/nautilus`. If you remove this file, the quicklist will be regenerated automatically. You may have to log out and then log back in again to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks friend, I greatly appreciate your repsonse. That did the trick. Thank you very much.